# Error while passing data to flutter child

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to learn Google Flutter and I m having an issue while trying to pass a data to a child .

For now, I m having two widgets : one that should display a list of pokemons, and one representing a pokemon.

From the ListPokemon one, I'm creating each line using :

```
  List<Pokemon> _createRow() {
    return this
        ._pokemons
        .map((pokemonData) => new Pokemon(pokemonName: 'Super pokemon name'))
        .toList();
  }
```

From the PokemonCard, I've tried to make something like :

```
class Pokemon extends StatelessWidget {
  Pokemon({Key key, this.pokemonName}) : super(key: key);

  final String pokemonName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(pokemonName); // prints the argument
    return new Card(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
            title: const Text(pokemonName), // gives : Arguments of constant creation must be constant expressions
            subtitle: const Text('That is a weird pokemon :O'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that something is going wrong right here :

```
title: const Text(pokemonName), // gives : Arguments of constant creation must be constant expressions
```

And I don't understand why.

What I wanted was simply to pass a string down to the child widget and display it on the screen.

Can anybody help me understand this error ?

EDIT : I've try to move `const Text` => `new Text`. Same thing occurs :(

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem too.
The main problem is you define the "ListTile" as "const". Remove "const" should make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `const` widgets, instantiate them with `new`. Since you're having dynamic content, they can't be `const` anyway :)

```
    children: <Widget>[
      new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
        title: new Text(pokemonName), 
        subtitle: const Text('That is a weird pokemon :O'),
      ),
    ],
```